# In Pycharm/Intellij, how can I format HTML with newline after DIV?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want the HTML code formatter to insert a newline after any DIV tag.

Is this possible in Pycharm / Intellij?  I've fiddled with the various preferences in Editor/Code style/HTML but nothing I see can do the job.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reformatting code? Go to Search Everywhere > "reformat code" > press enter

Comment: try removing `h3` from **Don't break if inline content** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML** - does it help?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac yes this issue is about the code formatter.

Comment: @lena appears to work thanks